# unexplained crash in my 3x+1 visualization program

Tags: python, math, crash

This is my first forum post, and I'm fairly new to coding.

I have a problem with my code. I recently watched a video by Veritasium on YouTube where he talked about the 3x+1 theorem. I decided to do something fun with my newfound knowledge and make a visualizer using python and turtle. However, every time I run it, the webpage (I'm using Codehs for this), freezes up. Here's my code.

```
highestnum = 1
numchosen = int(input("starting number? "))
rounds = 1

def odd(num):
    return (num*3)+1
    
def even(num):
    return num*2
    

while True:
    if numchosen%2 == 0:
        numchosen = even(numchosen)
    else:
        numchosen = odd(numchosen)
        
    if numchosen > highestnum:
        highestnum = numchosen
        
    if numchosen == 1:
        break

print("highest number: " + str(highestnum))
print("number of changes: " + str(rounds))
```

Please only answer about this crash I'm talking about, and not any optimizations I should do.

Comment: Apart from `dividing by 2`, inside the loop you might want to increment the `rounds` variable to avoid it being stuck at `1`. Further, note that it is not a theorem, but a conjecture. Also, there isn't a crash, it just runs on forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `even` function needs to divide by 2, not multiply.  Use the `//` operator for integer division (to avoid a floating point result):

```
def even(num):
    return num // 2
```

The original code was multiplying instead of dividing, so the value was growing exponentially, without end.

This problem is known as the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Answer (score 1):

In (def even) you need to divide even number with 2 in order to do 3x + 1 equation.

So improved version of the question will be:

```
highestnum = 1
numchosen = int(input("starting number? "))
rounds = 1

def odd(num):
    return (num*3)+1

def even(num):
    return num // 2
    

while True:
    if numchosen%2 == 0:
        numchosen = even(numchosen)
    else:
        numchosen = odd(numchosen)
        
    if numchosen > highestnum:
        highestnum = numchosen
        
    if numchosen == 1:
        break

print("highest number: " + str(highestnum))
print("number of changes: " + str(rounds))
```